# How can I assign a different address to an array?

Tags: c++

I want to pass an array to a function, then point that array variable to a new address altogether within said function.

I realize that arrays behave as pointers to the adress of their first element when passed to a function, so why the heck won't the address change for my array variable in main?

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 void passArrayByReference(int * array) { //passing array as.        pointer should let us modify it's address, correct?
     cout << "Address of array in function is: " << array << endl; 
     int * localArray = new int [2];
     //put some dummy values in our localArray
     localArray[0] = 9;
     localArray[1] = 9;
     array = localArray;
     cout << "Address of array in function is now: " << array <<      endl; 
 }

 int main()
 {
    int * array = new int [2];
    int totalElements = 2;
    //put some initial values into our dynamic 1D array
    array[0] = 0;
    array[1] = 1;
    //print our initial values
    for(int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++)
         cout << array[i] << endl;
    cout << "Address of array in main: " << array << endl; 
    passArrayByReference(array);
    cout << "Address of array in main: " << array << endl; 

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You can't assign to an array. But you are assigning to a *pointer*, so that is possible. But don't confuse arrays with pointers.

Comment: You have a memory leak right now. You should `delete []` the old array before assigning the new address and `delete []` the new one when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: You didn't pass the array by reference, you passed it by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you just need to include the '&' symbol in your function header. The '&' symbol is used to pass an argument by reference, as opposed to by value.

In this case you are passing the address to the first element of your array by reference, meaning that you can modify that address in the function, and the changes will be reflected in your main function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void passArrayByReference(int * &array) {
    cout << "Address of array in function is: " << array << endl; 
    int * localArray = new int [2];
    //put some dummy values in our localArray
    localArray[0] = 9;
    localArray[1] = 9;
    array = localArray;
    cout << "Address of array in function is now: " << array << endl; 
}

int main()
{
   int * array = new int [2];
   int totalElements = 2;
   //put some initial values into our dynamic 1D array
   array[0] = 0;
   array[1] = 1;
   //print our initial values
   for(int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++)
        cout << array[i] << endl;
   cout << "Address of array in main is: " << array << endl; 
   passArrayByReference(array);
   cout << "Address of array in main is now: " << array << endl; 

   //now print the values of our 'new' array
   cout << "The values of array are now:" << endl;
   for(int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++)
        cout << array[i] << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GregKartrin take care of memory leak, you are leaking memory at this moment

Comment: Agreed, you should delete all dynamically allocated variables off the heap when you no longer need them.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are variables as well.
That's why you need to pass `array` as a reference to `passArrayByReference` so you don't just modify the copy of it.

```
void passArrayByReference(int *&array)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to pass pointer by pointer or reference to make persistent change to it - that is change original pointer and not only **copy** of it in function body:

```
 void passArrayByReference(int *&array) {
     //...
     array = new_address;
     std::cout << "Address of array in function is now: " << array << std::endl; 
 }
// and here it is the same
```

And second you should assign valid address `new_address` and take care of memory that `array` referenced just before it entered the function, **to avoid memory leak**.